# directx game on laptops with two video adapters and the wrong one connected the output

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I'm having a problem with a directx 11 game I'm developing on laptops with two video cards. The normal case I'm running into (and I have this on my own laptop) is a weak intel card and a powerful nvidia card. Obviously I want the nvidia one and I've already got it enumerating the adapters and figuring out the correct one to create the device interface for.

The problem is nvidia one doesn't have an output. When you call EnumOutputs on the IDXGIAdapter interface you don't find any. And this makes sense because the laptop only has one screen and its attached to the intel adapter (you can find it by calling EnumOutputs on the intel IDXGIAdapter interface).

But this seemingly makes it impossible to create a fullscreen swap chain for that device (IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain fails when given the nvidia device and fullscreen settings even when I'm certain the other mode parameters are valid).

It seems like other games are figuring out a way around this. Off of my steam list for example Half-Life 2 seems to be running in fullscreen mode. However stardew valley is running in borderless windowed mode which I could do but has its own issues.

I'm aware that its possible to change the laptop's settings so the nvidia card is the dominate one. But I need this to work on customer's laptops where I can't expect them to deal with all that.

One potential solution might be create a device for both adapters and then create a swap chain on the intel one as a device shared resource https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11device-opensharedresource I'm not even sure if that's possible though. The docs are vague.

Before I go down a difficult potentially dead end though I'm wondering if anyone knows the solution.

Comment: That is an issue we were also struggling with. Currently we are using the approach to export the variables `NvOptimusEnablement = 1` and `AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 1` to the system and let it choose the right adapter on its own. Working in most of all client cases.

Comment: That's something at least I didn't know about already. Does it work consistently and let you get into full screen mode on the right card?

Comment: Unfortunatley we didn't tested it with fullscreen as our application is working in borderless windowed mode. But with these flags we fixed the problem, that the system switches graphic adapters at runtime leading to errors. Since we applied them we only had a rough 5% of pc where the graphics adapter had to be chosen manually in the system.

Comment: It does fix the fullscreen problem in my local tests at least. When NvOptimusEnablement is set the nvidia card appears first in EnumAdapters and the output is seen as attached to that card.